# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int while storing a string

Tags: android, azure-mobile-services

I'm getting the weirdest error. Im attempting to store a String to Azure Mobile Service Table and I'm getting this exception. ( Being thrown for a GCM ID I'm generating"

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "C3960965-ECE0-4533-B99D-84DB3881A50F"

public class User
{
    private int id;
    private String gcmChannel;
    public User()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters
     *
     */

    public String getRegistrationId() {
        return gcmChannel;
    }


    public final void setRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        gcmChannel = registrationId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change in the tables created in Azure Mobile Services - the tables by default now have ids of type string (instead of integer, as before). If you change your type definition to the following:

```
public class User
{
    private String id;
    private String gcmChannel;
    // ... rest the same
}
```

It should work fine. Notice that you'll also need the latest Azure Mobile Services SDK for Android  (version 1.1.0) which has support for types with string ids - you can find that SDK at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=mobile.

You can find the announcement of this change in the [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/f020a4e2-9301-4318-9023-3a1668959221), or more information about it in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/11/23/new-tables-in-azure-mobile-services-string-id-system-properties-and-optimistic-concurrency.aspx).